# ReactJS Map Function : Not able to fetch all data on browser but its data shown on console window

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I am using map function of reactjs and not able to fetch data of an array on browser but its value shown on console windows.

```
import React, {useEffect } from 'react'
import { loadData } from '../Redux/actions/action';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {
    const dispatch=useDispatch()
    // const records=useSelector((state)=>state.blogReducer)
    const records=[{
        title:"MyRecord",
        category:"Redux",
        content:"My Content"
    }]


    useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(loadData());
    },[dispatch])

    return ( <>
        <div className='text-right m-1 p-1 pr-3' style={{"backgroundColor":"lightgreen","height":"40px"}}>
            <Link className="btn btn-primary btn-sm" to="/new">
            New Post 
          </Link>
        </div>
            <div className='text-center m-4'>
                 {/* <div style={{"border":"2px solid", "width":"400px","marginLeft":"450px","height":"40px"}}> */}
                    {/* <a href="#">This is best react post</a> */}
                    {/* load all content here */}
                    {/* <br /> */}
                 {/* </div> */}
                 {records.map((record)=>{
                        <div>{record.title},{record.category},{record.content}</div>
                        {console.log(record.title)}
                    })}
            </div>

    </> );
}
```

export default Home;
`**
Please help if you are able to find the problem thanks in advance.

Comment: Missed a return ?

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a `return` in your .map

```
{records.map((record) => {
  return <div>{record.title},{record.category},{record.content}</div>
})}
```

### Explanation:

When using arrow functions, if there is a single expression specified, it becomes the implicit return value.

```
const func = (x) => x * x;
// concise body syntax, implied "return"
```

However, in a block body, you must use an explicit return statement.

```
const func2 = (x, y) => {
  return x + y;
};
```

Comment: Thanks .  I am stuck from tomorrow to understand what is the problem with code. my fault .